# calculate daily minimum for 3d matrix data

Tags: matlab

I have a large 3d matrix of air temperatures for the entire earth, with the data formatted as lon x lat x time at hourly resolution. I want to find a robust way of calculating the daily minimum temperature for each lat/lon location. An example:

```
lon = -180:10:180;
lat = -90:10:90;
time = datenum('2009-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):1/24:datenum('2009-01-05 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
data = randn(length(lon),length(lat),length(time));
```

This is my data. It includes the air temperatures for different locations, provided at hourly resolution. The code below is my attempt at calculating the minimum value for each day.

```
% find number of unique days
datev = datevec(time);
[ia,ib,ic] = unique(datev(:,1:3),'rows');
uic = unique(ic);

% first re-structure data to 2d matrix
rdata = nan(length(time),length(lon)*length(lat));
for i = 1:length(ic);
    dd = data(:,:,i);
    rdata(i,:) = dd(:);        
end

% then calculate the minimum value for each day
min_data = nan(length(uic),length(lon)*length(lat));
for i = 1:length(uic);
    idx = find(ic == uic(i));    
    min_data(i,:) = min(rdata(idx,:),[],1);
end
min_data = reshape(min_data,length(lon),length(lat),length(uic));
```

I think this answer is correct, at least is seems to be when I look at the answers.

The question I have is (1) Is my method correct, and (2) is there a better way of doing this, rather than having to restructure the data and loop through the different uniuque days. I considered using accumarray but coulnd't work out how to work it with a 3d matrix.

Any adive is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your output third output from `unique` as the input to `accumarray` to group your data. As the second input your can provide all numbers between `1` and the size of your data (`numel(ic)`). Then for the fourth input you can create an anonymous function which will receive the indices (for the third dimension) that correspond to each day  and it can use these to grab the temps for all latitude/longitudes for this day and you can compute the minimum for each lat/long by computing the `min` along the third dimension.

```
datev = datevec(time);
[~,~,ic] = unique(datev(:,1:3),'rows');

min_temps = accumarray(ic, (1:numel(ic))', [], @(x){min(data(:,:,x), [], 3)});
min_temps = cat(3, min_temps{:})
```

The nice thing about this approach is that it doesn't necessarily require exactly 24 samples in a day. If you *can* guarantee 24 samples, you could just reshape your data and then compute the `min` without the use of `accumarray`.

```
reshaped = reshape(data, size(data, 1), size(data, 2), 24, []);
min_temps = squeeze(min(reshaped, [], 3));
```